# How to stop touchpal providing a daily summary?

Tags: keyboard, ads

I like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cootek.smartinputv5) keyboard app as it has a lot of flexibility with accessing symbols for markdown that I use on stackexchange as well as its edit screen.

[image: TouchPal keyboard can write opening and closing parens and leave the cursor inside]
[image: the TouchPal edit page]

<sub>Click image(s) for larger version</sub>

But it also 'helpfully'(!) provides a daily summary of what apps you use (creepy?) along with a half-screen advertisement. I really don't want that.

Here's an example:

[image: the daily summary]

<sub>Click image for larger version</sub>

It's not even useful or accurate!

Is there anyway to stop it from doing that? I've not found a setting for this,  nor a way to roll back the installed version to before this feature got added.

I'm in lollipop if it matters, with an Xperia Z5 compact. It might be able to upgrade to marshmallow.

How can I disable this feature, preferably without rooting my device?

Comment: Give us a link of the app and the version you're using. Is your device rooted? Can you post a screenshot where it shows that summary or advert or both? As for rolling back, you can find its previous version (from some third-party website) which didn't have this issue and install it using [tag:adb] with command `adb install -d APK_PATH`.

Comment: @Firelord added a link to the app and specified I don't want to root my device to do this (I.e. it's not already).  Have snapped a picture is the pop-up but when I set it I will.

Comment: What is your Android version? If it's Marshmallow, disable the relevant permissions related to app management

Comment: Also, there should be an in-app purchase relating to a Pro version or removing ads.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury alas I'm on lollipop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems they recently added an option to disable it:

TouchPal -> Settings -> General Settings -> uncheck Daily Summary

The new interface to disable daily summary (22 Nov 2016):

TouchPal--> Settings--> Look & Feel --> uncheck Daily Summary

Comment: General settings option is not there as of now, wondering if I have to login or is this moved to premium option? It's not there in free version at least anymore.

Answer (score 3):

In Touchpal 2016, got to settings, looking & feel, and uncheck daily summary towards the bottom of the listing.

Comment: A more up-to-date answer than the selected one.

Comment: This is the correct answer as of Jan 2017, the other accepted answer is no longer valid.

Answer (score 2):

Install an old version (eg. 5.7.8.8), you can search for it online. Mind that installing apps from outside the app store could be VERY dangerous. Please be careful.

You may have to uninstall Touchpal first and then install the old version.

Then in the Play Store app, disable automatic updates for all the apps. When you have some updates pending, do a "update all" and quickly open the Touchpal app store entry and cancel the update just for Touchpal.

This is my hand-made solution. I am "stuck" on version 5.7.8.8 and it works well so far. My touchpal has a christmas-themed icon but that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on marshmallow and have disabled TouchPals permission to draw over other apps so I'm presuming this is what will need to be done to fix the issue, I will update this is it works

Comment: And did it work?

Answer (score 0):

You click on the hand in the upper left hand corner, scroll to the second page of options and click settings chick on the little square of bars in the upper left hand corner, scroll to settings, scroll to "look and feel" scroll down to "daily summary" and un-check the box. This will stop the annoying daily summary.

Comment: Is this an update to [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/139890/11675) answer?

Answer (score 0):

you cant delete the floating icon if you are using the latest version. The easiest way is to download older version of touchpal. it will solved your problem instantly.

Comment: The questioner already said, "I've not found ... a way to roll back the installed version," so you should describe how to do this for your suggestion to be helpful.

Answer (score -2):

They will make it an option to have that annoying screen pop up daily. Before the end of February they say there will be an update that fixes this. Saw that info on their Facebook page.